# Get DOM from React Reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the [dom-to-image](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) tool with a react reference but I haven't been able to get it to work.

For example, if I have the following:

```
<div id="getMe">Stuff here</div>
```

This works perfectly:

```
const getMe = document.getElementById('getMe');

domtoimage
.toPng(getMe)
.then(function(dataUrl) {
    console.log(dataUrl);
})
```

However, if I do this:

```
<div ref={this.reference}>Stuff here</div>
```

And do the above code on the reference, I get the following error:

> TypeError: node.cloneNode is not a function at makeNodeCopy (dom-to-image.js:160)

Does anyone know how to actually get the DOM from a reference?

**GOAL**: The overall goal here is to be able to export a SVG/IMAGE from a reference object.

Comment: how do you pass that? it should be `domtoimage.toPng(this.reference.current)`

Comment: what are you doing with the ref? are you trying to access it with document.getElementbyIID???
you can find the object reference in this.reference.current... try to console it